# Find counterexample product of weak$^*$ convergent product

Tags: functional-analysis

The following assertion is true in the case $1<p<\infty$ but for $p=\infty$ in general not. So I want to find a counterexample. Can someone help me?

So find $f_n, g_n \in L^{\infty}(0,1)$ such that $f_n \rightharpoonup^* f,g_n \rightharpoonup^* g$ but $f_n g_n$ does not weak$^*$ converge to $fg$.

Comment: Let $f_n(x)=g_n(x)=n$ for $x\in (0,1/n^2)$ and $ f_n(x)=g_n(x)=0$ for $x\in [1/n^2,1)$ . If $h(x)=1$ for all $x$ then we have $\int_0^1 f_ng_nh=1$ but I have not confirmed that $f_n$ converges weak$^*$ to $0$.

Comment: This statement is also not true for $p \in (1,\infty)$! Btw. you can usually take $f_n = g_n$.

Comment: any other suggestions? :)